# Undefined when import methods from '@videosdk.live/react-native-sdk'

Tags: react-native, package, videosdk.live

For my RN project, I use '@videosdk.live/react-native-sdk'.When I try to import a method from the library I get undefined. I can't figure out what's going on. I did everything according to the instruction and set it up correctly.
The problem is not even in the setup, but I installed the package '@videosdk.live/react-native-sdk', but I can't import methods from it.

`import VideoSdk from '@videosdk.live/react-native-sdk';` I used this import but got `undefined`

Comment: In which emulator are you running code? Android or iOS.

Comment: I was launching my app on ios emulator and real device (iphone)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import VideoSdk. You need to import some other components like:

```
import {
MeetingProvider,
useMeeting,
useParticipant,
MediaStream,
RTCView,
} from "@videosdk.live/react-native-sdk";
```